# node.js , socket.io - disconnect event delay when internet connection dies

Tags: node.js, socket.io, disconnect

I notice that `socket.on('disconnect')` fires immediately when I close browser tab. But it fires approximately in a minute after internet connection dies. I'm using socket.io module. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: this is by design, heartbeat timeout is set to 60 seconds https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#wiki-server

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12846918/1221252

Comment: Should I set heartbeat timeout to 1 second? Does it have some negative sides?

Comment: What do you want to fix in it? I mean do you want your client to emit disconnect event the very moment it loses internet connection?

Answer (score 13):

You have to use `pingTimeout` and `pingInterval` options on the server side to control this:

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  pingInterval: 10000
});
```

- `pingTimeout` (`Number`): how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (`5000`)
- `pingInterval` (`Number`): how many ms before sending a new ping packet (`25000`)

More details about params: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1

Comment: great! how is it connected with engine.io? isn't engine.io built over socket.io? i can't find any documentation for socket.io. again thanks, that helped me very much!

Comment: You welcome. Engine.io is a lower level library than socket.io so the socket.io is built on engine.io. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542502/whats-the-difference-between-engine-io-and-socket-io